# WPF basic data binding from one xaml page to other

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on small project and I am using only 3 small XAML pages.
It suppose to be DVD shop app where you can add movie and list movies simple as that. I am having problem with data binding (or storing data somewhere just not db)

movieslist.XAML: (I want to bind data and to present it here)

```
<Page x:Class="DeNiro.movielist"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeNiro"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="movielist">

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

addmovies.xaml.cs: (On button click create new object and set datacontext)

```
private void btn_add_movie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Movie NewMovie = new Movie { Name = "kriticar" };
        this.DataContext = NewMovie;
    }
```

Movie.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DeNiro

{
    public class Movie
    {
        public Movie()
        {
            test = "";
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public string genre { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public List<Movie> Moviez { get; set; }
        public string test;
    }
}
```

PROBLEM: I am getting nothing, textbox is empty
even if I try simple examples, where I create object and set data like this

```
Movie NewMovie = new Movie { Name = "kriticar" };
public addmovie()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = NewMovie;
    }
```

I have tried all kind of different solutions but I cant get data from XAML a to XAML b... please help

Comment: How is the "page" used in all this? I am confused, that the button click event assigns the movie-model to "this.".? Is there an over all Window/user control?

Comment: @Malior I am confused as I am new to wpf and c#. Well I have tried DataContext = this; and bunch of other solutions but no luck... All I need piece of data from 1 XAML page to 2 XAML page (name bind to textbox)

Comment: I still don't undertstand how the page (DeNiro.movielist.xaml) is used. If it is used in another view(UserControl or Window), then you will need to assign the DataContext to that page, not to "this". Example: in btn_add_movie_Click, make "myMoviePage.DataContext = new Movie { Name = "kriticar" }";
myMoviePage would by the x:Name of the page.
However, I recommend to check this link (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) to get things right.